# Find all other tables that use a current table (oracle database)

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I am doing some analysis work with some old code that uses Oracle database (11g). I've got a code Table and would like to find all the tables, Triggers, etc that calls/uses this table (like foreign key reference). I use Oracle SQL Developer currently and not sure if I can write a query to find this. Is there a way that I can find all references to my current table in the same Schema? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data dictionaries to do this, but which data dictionary to use depends on the type of object in question. Because you want to find several different types of objects, you'll need to use several dictionaries, and, if you want the result all in one query, you will have to connect a few queries together via unions.

The following query (2 queries connected into one by a union) will show you tables with keys referencing table xyz in schema xyz, and also the names of triggers using table xyz in schema xyz (replace table and schema name with whatever you're searching on:

```
select 'Table has key referencing this table' as match_type, table_name
  from all_constraints
 where constraint_type = 'R'
   and r_constraint_name in
       (select constraint_name
          from all_constraints
         where constraint_type in ('P', 'U')
           and table_name = 'TABLE_XYZ'
           and owner = 'SCHEMA_XYZ')
union all
select distinct 'Table is used by this trigger', trigger_name
  from all_triggers
 where table_name = 'TABLE_XYZ'
   and owner = 'SCHEMA_XYZ'
```

For other types of objects, use the same method with the next appropriate dictionary, and connect by a union. You will find this helpful:

http://www.oracle.com/pls/tahiti/tahiti.catalog_views

Note that I use the all_ dictionaries in the query above. Each has an equivalent dba_ and user_ dictionary. The all_ ones act as a dictionary for all objects to which the currently logged in user (you) has access. The dba_ one acts as a dictionary for all objects in the database, but you need to have the privilege to use the dba_ dictionaries, so I didn't use them in the above query (if you do have access, replace all_ with dba_). The user_ dictionaries act as a dictionary for all objects owned by the current user/schema.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks very much.. It gives me few entries in 2 columns - match_type and Table_name as per the query. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the tables and triggers, you may also want to check if there are any code objects referencing your table. ie. procedures, packages.

So you can add a third query:

select NAME,TYPE from all_dependencies where REFERENCED_OWNER='&your_table_owner' and REFERENCED_NAME='&your_table_name';